# cannot @extend third party css framework in scss with Laravel Mix

Tags: css, sass, extend, laravel-mix

I'm working on a Laravel project with Tailwind Css framework.

I'm not a frontend developer, I'm a backend guy, so since now I just included Tailwind css and used its classes, but this lead me to have some elements with lots of classes to have the style defined, last of which is an action message div ended up having all these classes:

```
absolute bg-green-100 top-10 h-15 w-64 p-4 text-right rounded-md border-l-4 border-green-500
```

So I decided to learn a bit of scss, just enough to get rid of these situations.

I made my `test.scss` as

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

.action-message-success {
    @extend .absolute;
    @extend .bg-green-100;
    @extend .top-10;
    @extend .h-15;
    @extend .w-64;
    @extend .p-4;
    @extend .text-right;
    @extend .rounded-md;
    @extend .border-l-4;
    @extend .border-green-500;
}
```

and in my `webpack.mix.js` i just added

```
.sass('resources/css/test.scss', 'public/css')
```

But when compiling i get the error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .absolute !optional" to avoid this error.
  ╷
6 │     @extend .absolute;
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

I know I'm just missing something trivial, but i cannot figure out what.

Comment: did you fix this problem? @fudo

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using `!optional` at the end of your code snippet. Some classes need `!optional` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @apply instead of @extend ? (in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145771/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-global-third-party-class-into-a-css-module-in-next-js))

It works for me