# Is it possible to extend a global third party class into a CSS module in Next.js?

Tags: css, sass, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am using Next.js and CSS Modules. Right now in `_app.js` I am importing a global scss file like this:

```js
import 'public/scss/style.scss';
```

Inside this file, I have imported Bootstrap:

```css
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Suppose I have a component like `Footer.jsx`. I want to create a `Footer.module.scss` that uses Bootstrap's `.container`. I have tried something like this:

```css
.myClass {
  @extend .container;
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work:

```
SassError: The target selector was not found
```

What is the best way to achieve what I try to do?

Comment: Have you checked out https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/ - you can add the @include or extend things by variables like color: $red-100. I couldn't find list of available variables. If you're not committed to bootstrap, I'd recommend tailwind.  It allows you to do exactly what you are trying to do like .footer { @ apply w-full color-red-100; heigh: 100px;}; but it also purges unused classes when you build.

Comment: @SeanW the only problem I have with this is that I cannot include all bootstrap because CSS Modules will complain that selector :root is not pure. Anyway, if I only include the files from Bootstrap that are of my interest and I have `n` CSS Modules importing these files, wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: I haven't used next + css modules in about a year but I believe you can import bootstrap first in your _app and you don't have to in your modules.   Here's some info on making boostrap more efficient - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/ checkout the unsed/purge section as well.

Comment: @SeanW Well I tried that but still you can't extend bootstrap classes within a CSS Module without having to import all of those SCSS files.